# Path of File from Home Folder

Tags: bash, path

How can I get the Path of a file who is present in one of the subfolders of my Home folder ?

For example for the file `/Users/Me/Foo/Bar/baz` I'd like to have `~/Foo/Bar/baz`

Comment: The tilde `~` expands to $HOME, `/Users/Me/Foo/Bar/baz` and `~/Foo/Bar/baz` are equivalent.

Comment: Isn't it possible to get an ~ on stdout as result ?

Comment: So you want a way of preventing the tilde from being expanded?

Comment: Not sure I'm following the question. You want to provide the filename but have the path to that file returned. The file will always exist in your home dir. Must it be returned in the ~/.../.../... format or is the full expanded path ok? If so, what about just using find - e.g. `find ~ -name baz`

Comment: No, actually I only want the path behind the home folder. It's for a bash script, I can add the ~/ afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ls works if given the path. So for baz, `ls $PWD/baz` should give the complete path. If you need to replace /Users/Me with ~, you can use sed:

```
ls $PWD/baz | sed "s_`ls -d ~|tr -d '\n'`_~_"
```

Comment: Btw, how would you store the result of this in a bash variable ?

Comment: To avoid escaping backticks use $(): myvar=$(ls $PWD/baz | sed "s_`ls -d ~|tr -d '\n'`_~_")